# Does time elapse when the player is in a menu in single-player mode?

Tags: factorio

There is an achievement named *There is no spoon*

> Finish the game in 8 hours

There is other achievement based on time.

I was asking myself if the time lapses when the player is in the Reasearch, Production or Electricity pannel in single-player mode. Obviously, we can notice the game is stopping, but does the "play-time" pass?

Comment: 99% sure it doesn't count the paused time. But I've only really played multiplayer

Comment: Finishing the game in 8 hours is one heck of a difficult achievement. By 8 hours into a map, I've just about started getting my rail network started and my logistics bots working well.

Comment: @Fambida yes and no, the record is like 2 hours, and that's with a single person, it stands to reason that multiple people would be able to do it faster than the could by themselves (assuming no conflicts etc). And when you're aiming for just completion you can skip a lot of things such as bots, rails, plus you'd do it on peaceful etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't count.

When you go to the achievement list (the rightmost icon in the icon list in the upper right) you can see how much time is remaining. You can also pin the achievement (magnet-icon) to always have it in sight while you play.

You will notice that the countdown is paused while you are in the Esc menu.